# Runtime discrepancy when using CompletableFuture on an IO bound task

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future, jmh

My understanding of the JVM multi-threading model is that when a thread executes an IO call, the thread is `BLOCKED` and put into a waiting queue by the JVM/OS until data is available.

I am trying to emulate this behavior in my code and running a benchmark with various thread sizes, using `JMH` and `CompletableFuture`.

However, the results are not what I expected. I was expecting a constant execution time (with thread/context switching overhead) irrespective of the number of threads (with memory limitations), since the tasks are IO bound and not CPU bound.

[image: Async IO results]

My cpu is a 4 core/ 8 thread laptop processor, and even with 1 or 2 threads, there is a discrepancy in the expected behavior.

I'm trying to read a 5MB file (separate file for each thread) in the async task. At the start of each iteration, I create a `FixedThreadPool` with the required number of threads.

```
@Benchmark
public void readAsyncIO(Blackhole blackhole) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> readers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i =0; i< threadSize; i++) {
         int finalI = i;
         readers.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> readFile(finalI), threadPool));
    }

    Object result =  CompletableFuture
                     .allOf(readers.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
                     .get();
    blackhole.consume(result);
}
```

```
@Setup(Level.Iteration)
public void setup() throws IOException {
    threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadSize);
}
```

```
@TearDown(Level.Iteration)
public void tearDown() {
    threadPool.shutdownNow();
}
```

```
public byte[] readFile(int i)  {
    try {
        File file = new File(filePath + "/" + fileName + i);
        byte[] bytesRead = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        inputStream.read(bytesRead);
        return bytesRead;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CompletionException(e);
    }
}
```

And the JMH config,

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Warmup(iterations = 3)
@Fork(value=1)
@Measurement(iterations = 3)
public class SimpleTest {

    @Param({ "1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32", "50", "100" })
    public int threadSize;
    .....

}
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ? Or are my assumptions incorrect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems reasonable. With single thread you see that 1 file takes ~ 2ms to deal with, adding more threads would lead to longer average per thread because each `read(bytesRead)` on very large size is likely to do multiple disk reads so there may be opportunity for IO blocking and thread context switching, plus - depending on the disks - more seek times.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about multiple reads for reading the entire file. 
I reduced the file size, and it's now behaving more like what I was expecting, with the thread overheads.